# Accessing a text file in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

I've got a text file in my WPF application which is located in a subfolder, so apologies for advance for the terrible ASCII.

```
+Project
+--+Subfolder
|  +--TextFile.txt
|
+--App.config
+--App.xaml
+--etc.
```

The build action on this text file is Resource and I'm trying access the content as a string in my program, but I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing.

Trying to access the file through `Properties.Settings.Default` doesn't work, apparently there's only a ConnectionString resource in my program.

I can't do it in XAML because for whatever reason there's no `Source` property

```
<!-- somewhere up the top of App.xaml... -->
xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<clr:String Source="pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/Textfile.txt"/>
```

The FindResource method can't find it either.

```
FindResource("Usage.txt"); //ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException
```

All I'm trying to do is reference the text file, read it as a string and use that string. Otherwise I have to embed a 50 line verbatim string in the method call. Because that's totally a good idea. /s

In WinForms it was as simple as: `Properties.Settings.Default.TextFile.ToString();` but nothing seems to work here.

I should point as well that this file shouldn't be included in the output directory, it needs to be embedded in the application or whatever the term is.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/TextFile.txt");
var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

using (var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream.Stream))
{
    var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Subfolder/TextFile.txt"))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work. `DirectoryNotFoundException.  Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Project\bin\Debug\Subfolder\TextFile.txt'`

Comment: This text file should not be accessible from the output folder either. It needs to be an embedded resource, or whatever the term in WPF is.

Comment: in the property windows set the value "Copy to output directory" to: "copy always"

Comment: The text file needs to be embedded in the .exe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
  string file = @"pack://application:,,,/" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/Subfolder/TextFile.txt";
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(file)).Stream))
      {
          var data= sr.ReadToEnd();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, this is your project structure

```
+ProjectName
+--+imagesFolder
|  +--amogus.png
|
+--App.xaml
+--MainWindow.xaml
+--etc.
```

and you want to access the to amogus.png in your xaml window,
You have two ways:

> note this way the imagesFolder will be visible in the release build to users

1. to set amogus.png `Build Action` to `Content` and
   `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022#set-a-build-action),
   then `rebuild` from the build menu, then add this to the window xaml

```
    <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,/imagesFolder/amogus.png" ></Image>
```

> note this way the imagesFolder will be not visible in the release build to users

2. to set amogus.png `Build Action` to `Resource` and
   `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy` or `blank` [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022#set-a-build-action),
   then `rebuild` from the build menu, then add this to the window xaml

```
    <Image Source="/imagesFolder/amogus.png" ></Image>
```

[more detail](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2005/12/more-on-resource-loading-in-wpf.html)